# Application of the mean value theorem for Integrals

Tags: integration, derivatives

Suppose that $f(x)$ is a differentiable function in $[a,b]$, $f^{'}(x)$ is a monotone decreasing function in $(a,b)$, and $f^{'}(b)>0$. So how to prove that

> > $$
> > \big \vert \int_a^b \cos f(x)dx \big\vert \leq\frac{2}{f^{'}(b)}
> > $$

__

My main solution is as follow:
$$
\big \vert \int_a^b \cos f(x)\big) dx \big\vert=\big \vert \int_a^b \frac{\cos f(x)}{f^{'}(x)} d\big(f(x)\big)\big\vert\leq\frac{1}{f^{'}(b)}\big \vert \int_a^b \cos f(x)d\big(f(x)\big)\big\vert\leq\frac{2}{f^{'}(b)}
$$
However, someone pointed out that there are some mistakes. Really? Can you help me find the error(s), or just provide me with a right answer.

Comment: Note that $\int_a^b \cos (f(x))f'(x)dx=0$ doesn't imply, necessarily, $\int_a^b \cos (f(x)) f'(x)dx=0.$ So, your first inequality is not necessarily satisfied.

Comment: Seems to me that you are correct: $f'(x)\geq f'(b)>0$ gives your 1st inequality, while the 2nd inequality comes by noting that an antiderivative is just $\sin f(x)$... What am I missing?

Comment: @mfl: Well, it doesn't $I=\int_a^b \cos(f)f^{'}dx$ equals to zero or not, since $f^{'}(x)>0$ for all $a<x<b$. Specially, if $I=0$, the "=" holds, which is consistent with the conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer aims to show where your mistake is.

Consider $f(x)=\frac{\pi }{3}x(4-x), a=0,b=1.$ It is $f'(x)=\frac{\pi}{3}(4-2x)$ and $f''(x)=-\frac{2\pi}{3}.$ Since $f''(x)<0$ we have that $f'(x)$ is decreasing and  $f'(x)=\frac{\pi}{3}(4-2x)0$ on $[0,1].$ Moreover, $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=\pi.$ Thus,

$$\int_0^1 \cos (f(x))f'(x)dx=\left. \sin f(x)\right|_0^1=\sin\pi-\sin 0=0.$$

However,

$$I=\int_0^1 \cos(f(x)) dx\ne 0.$$

(See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+cos+%28pi%2F3++x+%284-x%29%29+dx+from+x%3D0+to+1

Thus, the inequality

$$\left|\int_a^b \frac{\cos f(x)}{f'(x)} f'(x) dx \right| \le \frac{1}{f'(b)}\left| \int_a^b \cos f(x) f'(x)dx\right|$$

$$0<|I|=\left|\int_0^1 \cos(f(x)) dx\right|\le \frac{1}{f'(1)}\left| \int_0^1 \cos f(x) f'(x)dx\right|=0 $$ cannot hold.

Your argument would be correct if you had an inequality as

$$\int_a^b \left|\frac{\cos f(x)}{f'(x)} f'(x) \right|dx  \le \frac{1}{f'(b)}\int_a^b \left|\cos f(x) f'(x)\right| dx,$$ but this is a completely different question.

Comment: Your example has a flaw: $f'(x) = 2\pi(1-x)$ not $\pi(2-x)$ so $f'(1) = 0$ in contradiction with $f'(1) > 0$.

Comment: @Winther Thank you for noticing the mistake. I have edited the answer to solve the problem.